# something went wrong with normals, i guess

Tags: texturing, faces, normals, extrude

guys! after I extruded some faces along normals, it really got my mesh funky. In solid veiw it is visible that something is wrong. But when you get some texture on it, it stretches like hell. Also, when i tried to subdivide, some faces went ok, but the others divided the surrounding instead. Is there something I could do to fix? you can see the faces from the second floor, where I did not use extr[image]ude along normals and obviously those are okey... please, help...

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*", "*help*", "*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: I don't see the issue from your screen shot.  You do know how to recover a previous version of your file?   Search in this website for how to do recovery.

Comment: it's not easy to understand, it looks like you ask different questions, we can see a shading problem, maybe right click in Object mode > Shade Flat? Or please explain more precisely and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: It certainly looks as if smooth shading's interpolation of normals doesn't simulate the surfaces you would like it to.. that could be split edges, inconsistent normals in the underlying geometry, ... all sorts.. the quickest diagnosis would come from a shared file, as moonboots suggests.